# Is there any difference or even slight difference between the following?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

United Kingdom, Britain, England, Wales and Scotland
I have seen it more than once written as "England and Wales" and I always thought Wales is part of England. I hope my question is not silly.

Before you say it is off topic or not related to learning English, I as a learner of English find all these words and I make no distinction between them. To me they are all the same.

Comment: You have a long comma-separated list and it's not clear which chunks are supposed to be compared. Also, what you're looking for seems to be a question on the proper terminology of political entities according to those regions; you'd probably do better to look up [Terminology of the British Isles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology_of_the_British_Isles).

Comment: Thank you friend. I just wanted to know the difference as I thought they were the same. I  realise the difference now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about geography than it is about English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: map of Great Britain]

United Kingdom *of **Great Britain** and **Northern Ireland*** = **Great Britain** + **Northern Ireland**

**Great Britain** = Wales + England + Scotland

- Scotland = a country
- Wales = a country

**Northern Ireland** = an island country

Comment: So, UK or GB is a kind of union amongst a number of countries. Thank you very much friend.

Comment: Please I would like to ask you more if you do not mind. Since they are a kingdom, they have one king or a queen, right even in this 21st century? The king rules his kingdom with a parliament like ancient times, Queen Elizabeth the first for example? Is it the same Great Britain as ancient times or it has gotten fewer lands than it used to be? I hope my questions are not stupid. You really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, we have a queen.  Queen Elizabeth the second.  As the picture above shows, Great Britain is an island, and it's still the same Great Britain as it was in Roman times.  Only the borders of the countries within the island have changed.  The history of the United Kingdom is very interesting and worth reading about, but this comment box is too small to explain much more.

Comment: Yes, it is very interesting and worth reading indeed. Thank you, friend.

Comment: You will often see 'England and Wales' written together as they are considered the same legal jurisdiction within the U.K., sharing the same court system.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Though Wales does have a devolved system of government in the same way that Scotland and Northern Ireland do.

Comment: @WS2 Yes although while Scotland has its own Parliment, Wales has only has an Assembly with lesser powers than the Scottish Parliment. The Scottish Parliment can introduce its own legislation in areas not controlled by Westminster, the Welsh Assembly can only amend laws passed by Westminster.